# Compare two arrays get unique values javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I have an object array called Banker and i have an array called remove_banker_id,

so in my code
remove_banker_id = [11, 99]. My banker object banker.id has 11 and 99 and i dont want to include them in my third array so how do i do tht?

My current code has this in my javascript file

```
   $.each(data, function( index, banker ) {
      $.each(lender_banker_id_array, function(index, banker_id) {
        if(parseInt(banker_id) !== banker.id) {
           banker_object
             .append($('<option>', {value: banker.id, html: banker.name }))
             .removeAttr('disabled');
         }
      })
   });
```

So basically if any lender_banker_id_array is in banker object, do not append it. But with this code it is not working properly.  How do i solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the jquery utility function `$.inArray()`

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

It returns the index of a value in an array. It returns -1 if the array does not contain the value.

```
$.each(data, function( index, banker ) {
    if($.inArray(banker.id, lender_banker_id_array) == -1) {
        banker_object.append($('<option>', {
           value: banker.id, 
           html: banker.name 
        })).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: neat, sweet answer @nathan. thnks bruv

Comment: I highly recommend using [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) it's faster and also is just better to use a native function against a non native.

Comment: @vihan1086 it probably is faster, but it's not supported in IE < 9. So if you want to have broad browser support you'll have to use a polyfill or something and at some point the trade off isn't worth the extra millisecond.